# How remove the date in template

Tags: titles

I want remove date in this template:

http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wenneker-article

I remove this line

```
\date{\today}
```

but this not work

[image]

i modify to \date{}

[image]

I want reduce the spacing

Comment: `\date{}` is enough to completely remove the date

Comment: @koleygr i edited my question

Comment: does `\date{\vspace{-5ex}}` helps as in the linked post (the answer of vanden)?

Comment: Seems the template does not suit your needs.

Comment: @koleygr it work perfectly

Comment: nice... marked as a duplicate... Happy TeXing!

Comment: The template loads package `titling` in the `structure.tex`. So you can use in the preamble of the `main.tex`:  `\date{}\predate{}\postdate{}` and `\postauthor{\vspace{10pt}\par\HorRule}` to remove the date and the additional space below the `\HorRule`.

Comment: @esdd i want put the date in the head

Comment: @x-rw Do you mean: `\postauthor{}` `\postdate{\par\HorRule\end{center}}` `\date{\today}`? Then the date would be above the rule.

Comment: @esdd my new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459621/modify-line-in-template-of-head