# Modify line in template of head

Tags: header-footer

This is the template
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wenneker-article

[image]

my code is :

```
\title{\Large Title.} % The article title
\author{
    \textbf{name} % Authors
    \newline\newline % Space before institutions
    \institution{Universidad }
}
\date{%
    $^1$Organization 1\\%
    $^2$Organization 2\\[2ex]%
    \today
}
```

I want the line to be placed below the date

Edit 1: i adding this code in main.tx

```
\author{
    \textbf{Juan perez, deving@gmail.com} % Authors
    \newline\newline % Space before institutions
    \institution{Universidad Antuart, sant pertersburgo}
}

% Example of a one line author/institution relationship
%\author{\newauthor{John Marston} \newinstitution{Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México, Mexico City, Mexico}}

\date{\today} % Add a date here if you would like one to appear underneath the title block, use \today for the current date, leave empty for no date
%\date{}
%\date{\vspace{-10ex}}
\preauthor{\begin{center}}
\postauthor{\end{center}}
\postdate{\par\HorRule\end{center}}
\postdate{\par\HorRule\end{center}}
```

this is the result

[image]

Comment: Please always post [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) instead of code fragments

Comment: @samcarte is template is very long the code

Comment: It's not that long and most of it is unrelated to your problem, so you can remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template loads package `titling` in the `structure.tex`. So you can add the following code in the preamble of the `main.tex`:

```
\postauthor{}
\postdate{\par\HorRule\end{center}}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If you want to center the author and the university use:

```
\preauthor{\begin{center}}
\postauthor{\end{center}}
\postdate{\par\HorRule\end{center}}
```

in the preamble of `main.tex` and change `\author` to:

```
\author{%
  \authorstyle{John Marston\textsuperscript{1,2,3} and Bonnie MacFarlane\textsuperscript{2,3}}% <- remove spurious space!!
  \\[\baselineskip]% <- changed
  \textsuperscript{1}\institution{Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México, Mexico City, Mexico}\\
  \textsuperscript{2}\institution{University of Texas at Austin, Texas, United States of America}\\
  \textsuperscript{3}\institution{\texttt{LaTeXTemplates.com}}
}
```

As MWE (only the relevant code of `structure.tex` and `main.tex` is used):

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}

% --- relevant part from structure.tex ---
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  top=1cm,
  bottom=1.5cm,
  left=2cm,
  right=2cm,
  includehead,
  includefoot,
  %showframe,
}
\setlength{\columnsep}{7mm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\newcommand{\authorstyle}[1]{{\large\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}\color{DarkRed}#1}}
\newcommand{\institution}[1]{{\footnotesize\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{sl}\color{Black}#1}}
\usepackage{titling} % Allows custom title configuration
\newcommand{\HorRule}{\color{DarkGoldenrod}\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}
\pretitle{
  \vspace{-30pt}%
  \HorRule\vspace{10pt} % <- note that this spurious space is needed!
  \fontsize{32}{36}\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}\selectfont%
  \color{DarkRed}%
}
\posttitle{\par\vskip 15pt}
\preauthor{}
\postauthor{\vspace{10pt}\par\HorRule\vspace{20pt}}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\newcommand{\initial}[1]{%
  \lettrine[lines=3,findent=4pt,nindent=0pt]{%
    \color{DarkGoldenrod}% Lettrine colour
    {#1}
  }{}%
}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\lettrineabstract}[1]{%
  \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstletter]
  \initial{\firstletter}\textbf{\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}}
}
% --- end relevant code from `structure.tex` ---

\title{Effective Methods for Capturing Cattle Rustlers}
\author{%
  \authorstyle{John Marston\textsuperscript{1,2,3} and Bonnie MacFarlane\textsuperscript{2,3}}% <- remove spurious space!!
  \\[\baselineskip]% <- changed
  \textsuperscript{1}\institution{Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México, Mexico City, Mexico}\\
  \textsuperscript{2}\institution{University of Texas at Austin, Texas, United States of America}\\
  \textsuperscript{3}\institution{\texttt{LaTeXTemplates.com}}
}

\preauthor{\begin{center}}% <- added
\postauthor{\end{center}}% <- added
\postdate{\par\HorRule\end{center}}% <- added
\date{\today}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lettrineabstract{Lorem ipsum ... \lipsum[1]}
\section{Section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: one more question please, I would like to center the name of the author and the university

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: i edited my question, see please

Comment: You have to change `\author` as in my MWE. Do not use `\newline\newline`! Replace it by `\\[\baselineskip]` and avoid the spurious space at the end of the line.